# Showing alert only once for each user in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to display a pop-up message when will appear when a Google Sheet is opened, but only once for each user when they open the document for the first time. The script below triggers the alert every single time, making the same user see a message multiple times, which I'm trying to avoid. Is there any straightforward way to limit onOpen triggers to only one time for each logged-in user?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('My pop-up message!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if(!prevlogin(e)) {
    ui.alert('My pop-up message!');
  }
}

function prevlogin(e) {
  const ps=PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  const useremail=e.user.getEmail();
  const date=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd");
  let lastlogin=ps.getProperty(useremail);
  if(!lastlogin) {
    ps.setProperty(useremail,date)
    return false;
  }else if(lastlogin!=date) {
    ps.setProperty(useremail,date)
    return false;
  }else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

You need to make this an installable onOpen(e).